# Review Summery dosen't show up

Tags: review

I use the bellow code to display short review summery.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/helper')->getSummaryHtml($product, 'short', false); ?>
```

What is wired to me is that on one web site it works, but on another one it want show up anything. And I use multiple domains. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using different theme for different websites ? I assume you have single Magento with multiple website setup

Comment: Hi Akhilesh, that is correct. I'm using different themes. Have a single Magento, with multiple website. Any idea?

Comment: Hi, my bad. I just sow that reviews are related to view store. Now, with the write store view I managed to displayed it correctly. Thanks Akhilesh for your effort.

Comment: @user15151 could you post your last comment as an answer to this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my bad. I just sow that reviews are related to view store. Now, with the write store view I managed to displayed it correctly. Thanks Akhilesh for your effort.